# <span> Inside <form> Tags

Tags: html, css

I am trying to to put `<span>` tags inside `<form>` tags like this:

**HTML:**

```
<form action="myAction" method="post">
    <!-- hidden input forms here -->

    <span class="leftBrace">[</span>
        <input type="submit" value="Evaluate" class="evaluate" />
    <span class="rightBrace">]</span>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
input[type="submit"].evaluate {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: #0000ff;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0;
}
input[type="submit"].evaluate:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.leftBrace {
    float: left;
    color: #0000ff;
}
.rightBrace {
    float: right;
    color: #0000ff;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

How do I make it so it appears like:

`[ Evaluate ]`

I specifically prefer the braces to be outside the `submit` link (hence I did not make it `value="[ Evaluate ]"`), because I do not want the braces to be underlined on hover.

---

**UPDATE:**

I removed the `float` from `.leftBrace` and `.rightBrace` and added `float: left` to `input[type=submit]`.

```
input[type="submit"].evaluate {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: #0000ff;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}
input[type="submit"].evaluate:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.leftBrace {
    color: #0000ff;
}
.rightBrace {
    color: #0000ff;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Remove `float` from `.leftBrace` and `.rightBrace`. `span` is `inline` by default so the `float`s are unnecessary. https://jsfiddle.net/qh7u0cda/

Comment: Add `float:left` to `input[type="submit"].course`

Comment: Hi, it did not work quite right. See update above for changes.

Comment: You've mixed two suggestions together which wont work. Don't add `float: left;` to `input[type="submit"].evaluate` if you remove `float` from `.leftBrace` and `.rightBrace`. @Eranda's suggestion will work if you keep the `float`s on `.leftBrace` and `.rightBrace`.

Comment: Hi @HiddenHobbes, I tried going with your suggestion first (no floats anywhere) and it appeared like [this](http://s14.postimg.org/6khie1vvx/new2.png).

Comment: @ohtph That would suggest that there are other styles not shown in your question that are having an effect on `input[type="submit"].evaluate` (most likely setting it to `display: block;`). Can you modify your question with code that reproduces the issue you are now seeing?

Comment: Thanks for the clue. The .css that came with the pre-made template was causing the problems. Removed styles pertaining to tables.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes, if you can find time to put a formal answer, I would be glad to upvote and accept it. Thanks for your assistance earlier.

Comment: @ohtph No problem, glad I could help. I've now posted my suggestions as a full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`span` are `display: inline;` by default and `input type="submit"` and are `display: inline-block;` so the `float`s in this case are unnecessary. Remove `float` from `.leftBrace` and `.rightBrace` and the content should display in one line.

```css
input[type="submit"].evaluate {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: #0000ff;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0;
}
input[type="submit"].evaluate:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.leftBrace {
    color: #0000ff;
}
.rightBrace {
    color: #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<form action="myAction" method="post">
    <!-- hidden input forms here -->

    <span class="leftBrace">[</span>
        <input type="submit" value="Evaluate" class="evaluate" />
    <span class="rightBrace">]</span>
</form>
```

**JS Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/qh7u0cda/

Answer (score 2):

float is not required for brace and remove it.

```
.leftBrace {

    color: #0000ff;
}
.rightBrace {

    color: #0000ff;
}
```

Comment: @ohtph — This answer said to stop the spans from floating. It did not say to make the input float. Don't make the input float as that breaks it.

Comment: I have also upvoted this. It was my pre-made template messing up the CSS.

Answer (score -2):

try without float :

```
<form action="myAction" method="post">
<!-- hidden input forms here -->

<span class="leftBrace">[</span><input type="submit" value="Evaluate" class="course" /><span class="rightBrace">]</span>
```

Comment: Either your html code inline or not, css doesn't care.

Comment: Yes, HTML is not WYSIWYG.